# Required for the first or second input form

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, required

I use Bootstrap 4.5, where it is possible to check the filling of the form, for example by inserting required.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_1" required>
```

How can I please check where I need to have input #1 OR input #2 filled in?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_2">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check whether the input#1 OR input#2 is filled. I recommend you to write a piece of javascript code to check that. if you are familiar with java script, create a separate javascript file and write a function to validate. or else you can just put a script tag inside the head tag as follows.

Javascript Validation:

```
<head>
     <script>
         function validateForm(){
             if(document.myform.input1.value == "" || document.myform.input2.value == ""){
                  alert("Both input1 and input2 should not be empty!");
             }
         }
     </script>
</head>
```

HTML form:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()" >  
    Input1: <input type="text" name="input1"><br/>  
    Input2: <input type="text" name="input2"><br/>  
    <input type="submit">  
</form>
```